# Ubuntu 18.04: XAMPP 8.0.3 + Laravel 8.* + PHP 8.*: Deprecation Notice + Unknown package has no name defined

Tags: 18.04, php, xampp, laravel

While trying to install Laravel 8, I got the following warning messages:

I have installed **XAMPP for Linux 8.0.3 and have PHP Version 8.0.3** installed within the XAMPP package.

I am suspecting that Laravel 8.* is not supporting yet php 8.* but I am not sure. Thank you.

```
$composer create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist "8.*"

Deprecation Notice: Required parameter $path follows optional parameter $schema in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/UndefinedConstraint.php:62
Deprecation Notice: Required parameter $path follows optional parameter $schema in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/UndefinedConstraint.php:108
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2

Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.16)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.16): Downloading (100%)         
Created project in blog

Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
```

and the following error message:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  Unknown package has no name defined ([{"name":"laravel\/installer","version  
  ":"v4.0.0","version_normalized":"4.0.0.0","source":{"type":"git","url":"htt  
  ps:\/\/github.com\/laravel\/installer.git","reference":"6dfb7306666b217f75d  
  50a03147591fcd895b97a"},"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.co  
  m\/repos\/laravel\/installer\/zipball\/6dfb7306666b217f75d50a03147591fcd895  
  b97a","reference":"6dfb7306666b217f75d50a03147591fcd895b97a","shasum":""},"  
  require":{"php":"^7.2.9","symfony\/console":"^4.0|^5.0","symfony\/process":  
  "^4.2|^5.0"},"require-dev":{"phpunit\/phpunit":"^8.0"},"time":"2020-09-03T0  
  7:52:54+00:00","bin":["bin\/laravel"],"type":"library","extra":{"branch-ali  
  as":{"dev-master":"3.x-dev"}},"installation-source":"dist","autoload":{"psr  
  -4":{"Laravel\\Installer\\Console\\":"src\/"}},"notification-url":"https:\/  
  \/packagist.org\/downloads\/","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Taylor   
  Otwell","email":"taylor@laravel.com"}],"description":"Laravel application i  
  nstaller.","keywords":["laravel"],"support":{"issues":"https:\/\/github.com  
  \/laravel\/installer\/issues","source":"https:\/\/github.com\/laravel\/inst  
  aller\/tree\/v4.0.0"},"install-path":"..\/laravel\/installer"},{"name":"psr  
  \/container","version":"1.1.1","version_normalized":"1.1.1.0","source":{"ty  
  pe":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/php-fig\/container.git","reference":  
  "8622567409010282b7aeebe4bb841fe98b58dcaf"},"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"htt  
  ps:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/php-fig\/container\/zipball\/8622567409010282  
  b7aeebe4bb841fe98b58dcaf","reference":"8622567409010282b7aeebe4bb841fe98b58  
  dcaf","shasum":""},"require":{"php":">=7.2.0"},"time":"2021-03-05T17:36:06+  
  00:00","type":"library","installation-source":"dist","autoload":{"psr-4":{"  
  Psr\\Container\\":"src\/"}},"notification-url":"https:\/\/packagist.org\/do  
  wnloads\/","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"PHP-FIG","homepage":"https  
  :\/\/www.php-fig.org\/"}],"description":"Common Container Interface (PHP FI  
  G PSR-11)","homepage":"https:\/\/github.com\/php-fig\/container","keywords"  
  :["PSR-11","container","container-interface","container-interop","psr"],"su  
  pport":{"issues":"https:\/\/github.com\/php-fig\/container\/issues","source  
  ":"https:\/\/github.com\/php-fig\/container\/tree\/1.1.1"},"install-path":"  
  ..\/psr\/container"},{"name":"symfony\/console","version":"v5.2.6","version  
  _normalized":"5.2.6.0","source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/  
  symfony\/console.git","reference":"35f039df40a3b335ebf310f244cb242b3a83ac8d  
  "},"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/symfony\/co  
  nsole\/zipball\/35f039df40a3b335ebf310f244cb242b3a83ac8d","reference":"35f0  
  39df40a3b335ebf310f244cb242b3a83ac8d","shasum":""},"require":{"php":">=7.2.  
  5","symfony\/polyfill-mbstring":"~1.0","symfony\/polyfill-php73":"^1.8","sy  
  mfony\/polyfill-php80":"^1.15","symfony\/service-contracts":"^1.1|^2","symf  
  ony\/string":"^5.1"},"conflict":{"symfony\/dependency-injection":"<4.4","sy  
  mfony\/dotenv":"<5.1","symfony\/event-dispatcher":"<4.4","symfony\/lock":"<  
  4.4","symfony\/process":"<4.4"},"provide":{"psr\/log-implementation":"1.0"}  
  ,"require-dev":{"psr\/log":"~1.0","symfony\/config":"^4.4|^5.0","symfony\/d  
  ependency-injection":"^4.4|^5.0","symfony\/event-dispatcher":"^4.4|^5.0","s  
  ymfony\/lock":"^4.4|^5.0","symfony\/process":"^4.4|^5.0","symfony\/var-dump  
  er":"^4.4|^5.0"},"suggest":{"psr\/log":"For using the console logger","symf  
  ony\/event-dispatcher":"","symfony\/lock":"","symfony\/process":""},"time":  
  "2021-03-28T09:42:18+00:00","type":"library","installation-source":"dist","  
  autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\":""},"exclude-from-class  
  map":["\/Tests\/"]},"notification-url":"https:\/\/packagist.org\/downloads\  
  /","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Fabien Potencier","email":"fabien@  
  symfony.com"},{"name":"Symfony Community","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com  
  \/contributors"}],"description":"Eases the creation of beautiful and testab  
  le command line interfaces","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com","keywords":[  
  "cli","command line","console","terminal"],"support":{"source":"https:\/\/g  
  ithub.com\/symfony\/console\/tree\/v5.2.6"},"funding":[{"url":"https:\/\/sy  
  mfony.com\/sponsor","type":"custom"},{"url":"https:\/\/github.com\/fabpot",  
  "type":"github"},{"url":"https:\/\/tidelift.com\/funding\/github\/packagist  
  \/symfony\/symfony","type":"tidelift"}],"install-path":"..\/symfony\/consol  
  e"},{"name":"symfony\/polyfill-ctype","version":"v1.22.1","version_normaliz  
  ed":"1.22.1.0","source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\  
  /polyfill-ctype.git","reference":"c6c942b1ac76c82448322025e084cadc56048b4e"  
  },"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/symfony\/pol  
  yfill-ctype\/zipball\/c6c942b1ac76c82448322025e084cadc56048b4e","reference"  
  :"c6c942b1ac76c82448322025e084cadc56048b4e","shasum":""},"require":{"php":"  
  >=7.1"},"suggest":{"ext-ctype":"For best performance"},"time":"2021-01-07T1  
  6:49:33+00:00","type":"library","extra":{"branch-alias":{"dev-main":"1.22-d  
  ev"},"thanks":{"name":"symfony\/polyfill","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symf  
  ony\/polyfill"}},"installation-source":"dist","autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony  
  \\Polyfill\\Ctype\\":""},"files":["bootstrap.php"]},"notification-url":"htt  
  ps:\/\/packagist.org\/downloads\/","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Ge  
  rt de Pagter","email":"BackEndTea@gmail.com"},{"name":"Symfony Community","  
  homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/contributors"}],"description":"Symfony po  
  lyfill for ctype functions","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com","keywords":[  
  "compatibility","ctype","polyfill","portable"],"support":{"source":"https:\  
  /\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill-ctype\/tree\/v1.22.1"},"funding":[{"url":"  
  https:\/\/symfony.com\/sponsor","type":"custom"},{"url":"https:\/\/github.c  
  om\/fabpot","type":"github"},{"url":"https:\/\/tidelift.com\/funding\/githu  
  b\/packagist\/symfony\/symfony","type":"tidelift"}],"install-path":"..\/sym  
  fony\/polyfill-ctype"},{"name":"symfony\/polyfill-intl-grapheme","version":  
  "v1.22.1","version_normalized":"1.22.1.0","source":{"type":"git","url":"htt  
  ps:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill-intl-grapheme.git","reference":"5601e0  
  9b69f26c1828b13b6bb87cb07cddba3170"},"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/  
  api.github.com\/repos\/symfony\/polyfill-intl-grapheme\/zipball\/5601e09b69  
  f26c1828b13b6bb87cb07cddba3170","reference":"5601e09b69f26c1828b13b6bb87cb0  
  7cddba3170","shasum":""},"require":{"php":">=7.1"},"suggest":{"ext-intl":"F  
  or best performance"},"time":"2021-01-22T09:19:47+00:00","type":"library","  
  extra":{"branch-alias":{"dev-main":"1.22-dev"},"thanks":{"name":"symfony\/p  
  olyfill","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill"}},"installation-so  
  urce":"dist","autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony\\Polyfill\\Intl\\Grapheme\\":""}  
  ,"files":["bootstrap.php"]},"notification-url":"https:\/\/packagist.org\/do  
  wnloads\/","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Nicolas Grekas","email":"p  
  @tchwork.com"},{"name":"Symfony Community","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.co  
  m\/contributors"}],"description":"Symfony polyfill for intl's grapheme_* fu  
  nctions","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com","keywords":["compatibility","gr  
  apheme","intl","polyfill","portable","shim"],"support":{"source":"https:\/\  
  /github.com\/symfony\/polyfill-intl-grapheme\/tree\/v1.22.1"},"funding":[{"  
  url":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/sponsor","type":"custom"},{"url":"https:\/\/gi  
  thub.com\/fabpot","type":"github"},{"url":"https:\/\/tidelift.com\/funding\  
  /github\/packagist\/symfony\/symfony","type":"tidelift"}],"install-path":".  
  .\/symfony\/polyfill-intl-grapheme"},{"name":"symfony\/polyfill-intl-normal  
  izer","version":"v1.22.1","version_normalized":"1.22.1.0","source":{"type":  
  "git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill-intl-normalizer.git","  
  reference":"43a0283138253ed1d48d352ab6d0bdb3f809f248"},"dist":{"type":"zip"  
  ,"url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/symfony\/polyfill-intl-normalizer\  
  /zipball\/43a0283138253ed1d48d352ab6d0bdb3f809f248","reference":"43a0283138  
  253ed1d48d352ab6d0bdb3f809f248","shasum":""},"require":{"php":">=7.1"},"sug  
  gest":{"ext-intl":"For best performance"},"time":"2021-01-22T09:19:47+00:00  
  ","type":"library","extra":{"branch-alias":{"dev-main":"1.22-dev"},"thanks"  
  :{"name":"symfony\/polyfill","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill  
  "}},"installation-source":"dist","autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony\\Polyfill\\I  
  ntl\\Normalizer\\":""},"files":["bootstrap.php"],"classmap":["Resources\/st  
  ubs"]},"notification-url":"https:\/\/packagist.org\/downloads\/","license":  
  ["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Nicolas Grekas","email":"p@tchwork.com"},{"name  
  ":"Symfony Community","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/contributors"}],"d  
  escription":"Symfony polyfill for intl's Normalizer class and related funct  
  ions","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com","keywords":["compatibility","intl"  
  ,"normalizer","polyfill","portable","shim"],"support":{"source":"https:\/\/  
  github.com\/symfony\/polyfill-intl-normalizer\/tree\/v1.22.1"},"funding":[{  
  "url":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/sponsor","type":"custom"},{"url":"https:\/\/g  
  ithub.com\/fabpot","type":"github"},{"url":"https:\/\/tidelift.com\/funding  
  \/github\/packagist\/symfony\/symfony","type":"tidelift"}],"install-path":"  
  ..\/symfony\/polyfill-intl-normalizer"},{"name":"symfony\/polyfill-mbstring  
  ","version":"v1.22.1","version_normalized":"1.22.1.0","source":{"type":"git  
  ","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill-mbstring.git","reference":  
  "5232de97ee3b75b0360528dae24e73db49566ab1"},"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"htt  
  ps:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/symfony\/polyfill-mbstring\/zipball\/5232de97  
  ee3b75b0360528dae24e73db49566ab1","reference":"5232de97ee3b75b0360528dae24e  
  73db49566ab1","shasum":""},"require":{"php":">=7.1"},"suggest":{"ext-mbstri  
  ng":"For best performance"},"time":"2021-01-22T09:19:47+00:00","type":"libr  
  ary","extra":{"branch-alias":{"dev-main":"1.22-dev"},"thanks":{"name":"symf  
  ony\/polyfill","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill"}},"installat  
  ion-source":"dist","autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony\\Polyfill\\Mbstring\\":""}  
  ,"files":["bootstrap.php"]},"notification-url":"https:\/\/packagist.org\/do  
  wnloads\/","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Nicolas Grekas","email":"p  
  @tchwork.com"},{"name":"Symfony Community","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.co  
  m\/contributors"}],"description":"Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extensi  
  on","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com","keywords":["compatibility","mbstrin  
  g","polyfill","portable","shim"],"support":{"source":"https:\/\/github.com\  
  /symfony\/polyfill-mbstring\/tree\/v1.22.1"},"funding":[{"url":"https:\/\/s  
  ymfony.com\/sponsor","type":"custom"},{"url":"https:\/\/github.com\/fabpot"  
  ,"type":"github"},{"url":"https:\/\/tidelift.com\/funding\/github\/packagis  
  t\/symfony\/symfony","type":"tidelift"}],"install-path":"..\/symfony\/polyf  
  ill-mbstring"},{"name":"symfony\/polyfill-php73","version":"v1.22.1","versi  
  on_normalized":"1.22.1.0","source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.co  
  m\/symfony\/polyfill-php73.git","reference":"a678b42e92f86eca04b7fa4c0f6f19  
  d097fb69e2"},"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/s  
  ymfony\/polyfill-php73\/zipball\/a678b42e92f86eca04b7fa4c0f6f19d097fb69e2",  
  "reference":"a678b42e92f86eca04b7fa4c0f6f19d097fb69e2","shasum":""},"requir  
  e":{"php":">=7.1"},"time":"2021-01-07T16:49:33+00:00","type":"library","ext  
  ra":{"branch-alias":{"dev-main":"1.22-dev"},"thanks":{"name":"symfony\/poly  
  fill","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill"}},"installation-sourc  
  e":"dist","autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony\\Polyfill\\Php73\\":""},"files":["b  
  ootstrap.php"],"classmap":["Resources\/stubs"]},"notification-url":"https:\  
  /\/packagist.org\/downloads\/","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Nicola  
  s Grekas","email":"p@tchwork.com"},{"name":"Symfony Community","homepage":"  
  https:\/\/symfony.com\/contributors"}],"description":"Symfony polyfill back  
  porting some PHP 7.3+ features to lower PHP versions","homepage":"https:\/\  
  /symfony.com","keywords":["compatibility","polyfill","portable","shim"],"su  
  pport":{"source":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill-php73\/tree\/v1.2  
  2.1"},"funding":[{"url":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/sponsor","type":"custom"},{  
  "url":"https:\/\/github.com\/fabpot","type":"github"},{"url":"https:\/\/tid  
  elift.com\/funding\/github\/packagist\/symfony\/symfony","type":"tidelift"}  
  ],"install-path":"..\/symfony\/polyfill-php73"},{"name":"symfony\/polyfill-  
  php80","version":"v1.22.1","version_normalized":"1.22.1.0","source":{"type"  
  :"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill-php80.git","reference  
  ":"dc3063ba22c2a1fd2f45ed856374d79114998f91"},"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"h  
  ttps:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/symfony\/polyfill-php80\/zipball\/dc3063ba2  
  2c2a1fd2f45ed856374d79114998f91","reference":"dc3063ba22c2a1fd2f45ed856374d  
  79114998f91","shasum":""},"require":{"php":">=7.1"},"time":"2021-01-07T16:4  
  9:33+00:00","type":"library","extra":{"branch-alias":{"dev-main":"1.22-dev"  
  },"thanks":{"name":"symfony\/polyfill","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony  
  \/polyfill"}},"installation-source":"dist","autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony\\P  
  olyfill\\Php80\\":""},"files":["bootstrap.php"],"classmap":["Resources\/stu  
  bs"]},"notification-url":"https:\/\/packagist.org\/downloads\/","license":[  
  "MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Ion Bazan","email":"ion.bazan@gmail.com"},{"name  
  ":"Nicolas Grekas","email":"p@tchwork.com"},{"name":"Symfony Community","ho  
  mepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/contributors"}],"description":"Symfony poly  
  fill backporting some PHP 8.0+ features to lower PHP versions","homepage":"  
  https:\/\/symfony.com","keywords":["compatibility","polyfill","portable","s  
  him"],"support":{"source":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/polyfill-php80\/t  
  ree\/v1.22.1"},"funding":[{"url":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/sponsor","type":"c  
  ustom"},{"url":"https:\/\/github.com\/fabpot","type":"github"},{"url":"http  
  s:\/\/tidelift.com\/funding\/github\/packagist\/symfony\/symfony","type":"t  
  idelift"}],"install-path":"..\/symfony\/polyfill-php80"},{"name":"symfony\/  
  process","version":"v5.2.4","version_normalized":"5.2.4.0","source":{"type"  
  :"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/process.git","reference":"313a  
  38f09c77fbcdc1d223e57d368cea76a2fd2f"},"dist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/  
  \/api.github.com\/repos\/symfony\/process\/zipball\/313a38f09c77fbcdc1d223e  
  57d368cea76a2fd2f","reference":"313a38f09c77fbcdc1d223e57d368cea76a2fd2f","  
  shasum":""},"require":{"php":">=7.2.5","symfony\/polyfill-php80":"^1.15"},"  
  time":"2021-01-27T10:15:41+00:00","type":"library","installation-source":"d  
  ist","autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony\\Component\\Process\\":""},"exclude-from  
  -classmap":["\/Tests\/"]},"notification-url":"https:\/\/packagist.org\/down  
  loads\/","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Fabien Potencier","email":"f  
  abien@symfony.com"},{"name":"Symfony Community","homepage":"https:\/\/symfo  
  ny.com\/contributors"}],"description":"Executes commands in sub-processes",  
  "homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com","support":{"source":"https:\/\/github.co  
  m\/symfony\/process\/tree\/v5.2.4"},"funding":[{"url":"https:\/\/symfony.co  
  m\/sponsor","type":"custom"},{"url":"https:\/\/github.com\/fabpot","type":"  
  github"},{"url":"https:\/\/tidelift.com\/funding\/github\/packagist\/symfon  
  y\/symfony","type":"tidelift"}],"install-path":"..\/symfony\/process"},{"na  
  me":"symfony\/service-contracts","version":"v2.4.0","version_normalized":"2  
  .4.0.0","source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/servic  
  e-contracts.git","reference":"f040a30e04b57fbcc9c6cbcf4dbaa96bd318b9bb"},"d  
  ist":{"type":"zip","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/symfony\/service  
  -contracts\/zipball\/f040a30e04b57fbcc9c6cbcf4dbaa96bd318b9bb","reference":  
  "f040a30e04b57fbcc9c6cbcf4dbaa96bd318b9bb","shasum":""},"require":{"php":">  
  =7.2.5","psr\/container":"^1.1"},"suggest":{"symfony\/service-implementatio  
  n":""},"time":"2021-04-01T10:43:52+00:00","type":"library","extra":{"branch  
  -alias":{"dev-main":"2.4-dev"},"thanks":{"name":"symfony\/contracts","url":  
  "https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/contracts"}},"installation-source":"dist","  
  autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony\\Contracts\\Service\\":""}},"notification-url"  
  :"https:\/\/packagist.org\/downloads\/","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name  
  ":"Nicolas Grekas","email":"p@tchwork.com"},{"name":"Symfony Community","ho  
  mepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/contributors"}],"description":"Generic abst  
  ractions related to writing services","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com","k  
  eywords":["abstractions","contracts","decoupling","interfaces","interoperab  
  ility","standards"],"support":{"source":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/ser  
  vice-contracts\/tree\/v2.4.0"},"funding":[{"url":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/sp  
  onsor","type":"custom"},{"url":"https:\/\/github.com\/fabpot","type":"githu  
  b"},{"url":"https:\/\/tidelift.com\/funding\/github\/packagist\/symfony\/sy  
  mfony","type":"tidelift"}],"install-path":"..\/symfony\/service-contracts"}  
  ,{"name":"symfony\/string","version":"v5.2.6","version_normalized":"5.2.6.0  
  ","source":{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfony\/string.git",  
  "reference":"ad0bd91bce2054103f5eaa18ebeba8d3bc2a0572"},"dist":{"type":"zip  
  ","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/symfony\/string\/zipball\/ad0bd91  
  bce2054103f5eaa18ebeba8d3bc2a0572","reference":"ad0bd91bce2054103f5eaa18ebe  
  ba8d3bc2a0572","shasum":""},"require":{"php":">=7.2.5","symfony\/polyfill-c  
  type":"~1.8","symfony\/polyfill-intl-grapheme":"~1.0","symfony\/polyfill-in  
  tl-normalizer":"~1.0","symfony\/polyfill-mbstring":"~1.0","symfony\/polyfil  
  l-php80":"~1.15"},"require-dev":{"symfony\/error-handler":"^4.4|^5.0","symf  
  ony\/http-client":"^4.4|^5.0","symfony\/translation-contracts":"^1.1|^2","s  
  ymfony\/var-exporter":"^4.4|^5.0"},"time":"2021-03-17T17:12:15+00:00","type  
  ":"library","installation-source":"dist","autoload":{"psr-4":{"Symfony\\Com  
  ponent\\String\\":""},"files":["Resources\/functions.php"],"exclude-from-cl  
  assmap":["\/Tests\/"]},"notification-url":"https:\/\/packagist.org\/downloa  
  ds\/","license":["MIT"],"authors":[{"name":"Nicolas Grekas","email":"p@tchw  
  ork.com"},{"name":"Symfony Community","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/co  
  ntributors"}],"description":"Provides an object-oriented API to strings and  
   deals with bytes, UTF-8 code points and grapheme clusters in a unified way  
  ","homepage":"https:\/\/symfony.com","keywords":["grapheme","i18n","string"  
  ,"unicode","utf-8","utf8"],"support":{"source":"https:\/\/github.com\/symfo  
  ny\/string\/tree\/v5.2.6"},"funding":[{"url":"https:\/\/symfony.com\/sponso  
  r","type":"custom"},{"url":"https:\/\/github.com\/fabpot","type":"github"},  
  {"url":"https:\/\/tidelift.com\/funding\/github\/packagist\/symfony\/symfon  
  y","type":"tidelift"}],"install-path":"..\/symfony\/string"}]).
```

Comment: Since that version of xampp was released on the 13 of March this year it might work better on 20.04

Comment: It should work with PHP 7.3+ or above...

Comment: I have removed XAMPP 8.0.3 
    cd /opt/lampp
    sudo ./uninstall
    sudo rm –r /opt/lampp
    sudo rm –r /opt/lampp
    Then have installed XAMPP 7.3.27

While trying to Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.16) got the following error message

    [ErrorException]            
    mkdir(): Permission denied

Tried 

sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs
sudo chown -R username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs

and got same error message than above question

    [UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
    Unknown package has no name defined (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem related in question seems to come from a permission conflict.

This set of permission is no working as expected:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs
sudo chown -R username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

I was oblige to set permissions this way:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs
sudo chown -R username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

and it works. While I know that giving 777 permissions is not recommanded that was the only way to make my installation works. I don't really know why but it works now.